# How to get sum of 3 sub count queries and group them using an attribute

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, subquery, count

I have 3 queries as follows:

For the date 2019-12-02, I am calculating 3 type of values. The total value for 2019-12-02 must be the sum of these 3 queries.

Q1

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM XAXBXC_charge_info_ABC_tbl 
WHERE date = '2019-12-02' 
AND cg_response_code = 0
```

Q2=>

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM XAXBXC_charge_info_ABC_tbl 
WHERE date = '2019-12-02' 
  AND topup_id = 10 
  AND topup_cg_response_code LIKE '0'
```

Q3=->

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM XAXBXC_charge_info_ABC_tbl 
WHERE date = '2019-12-02' 
  AND topup_id = 11 
  AND topup_cg_response_code LIKE '0'
```

I am trying to calculate and display sum as follows,

```
Date      | Sum 
2019-12-02|  234
```

eg:-

For a particular date, sum should be equal to the sum of Q1+Q2+Q3 and it must be grouped by the date column.

Can someone help me to achieve this? I have been stuck here for while now.

Comment: Q2 and Q3 are working as expected

Comment: You want multiple rows?

Comment: Yes, I want multiple rows

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT '2019-12-02' AS `Date`,
       SUM(cg_response_code = 0) 
     + SUM(     topup_id IN (10 , 11) 
            AND topup_cg_response_code LIKE '0'
          ) AS `Sum`
FROM XAXBXC_charge_info_ABC_tbl 
WHERE `date` = '2019-12-02'
```

PS. `LIKE '0'` condition is too strange. I'd recommend to replace it with `= 0` or `= '0'`, depending on the `topup_cg_response_code` datatype.

> This will work for a particular day, but I want records for each day – sadeee nadeee 2 mins ago

```
SELECT `date`,
       SUM(cg_response_code = 0) 
     + SUM(     topup_id IN (10 , 11) 
            AND topup_cg_response_code LIKE '0'
          ) AS `Sum`
FROM XAXBXC_charge_info_ABC_tbl
/* WHERE `date` BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2 */
GROUP BY `date`
```

Comment: This will work for a particular day, but I want records for each day

Comment: @sadeeenadeee This is not a problem... added.

Answer (score 1):

To get one row per day,

```
SELECT date,
       SUM( cg_response_code = 0 ) +
         SUM( topup_id IN (10, 11) AND topup_cg_response_code = 0 )  AS "Sum"
    FROM XAXBXC_charge_info_ABC_tbl 
    GROUP BY date
```

The pattern `SUM(boolean)` is a way to count the number of rows where "boolean" is TRUE.

This does all the work in a single pass over the data.